# Installing QT application on windows C Drive

Tags: windows, qt

I have a QT based application consisting of a configuration file(which is a text file with extension cfg) and an SQLite data file which gets installed with the application. 
Code verifies that the config file is present in the installation directory.

I have this weird problem where, when running the given cfg file is not updated, but the configurations are saved some where else. Even if I delete the cfg file, application still works. This is as if the OS is making a copy of the config files and database files and keep updating them instead of the actual file.

If application is installed in another drive (say d::), this behavior is not present. In addition if I run the application as administrator the app will edit and use the config file stored in C: drive.
Does such cache exist for editable files installed in C drive. If so how to go around it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since we don't know, what your code looks like, we cannot help you. If your configuration files uses the INI file API, chances are, that reads and writes get redirected to the registry. Easiest way to find out is to run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and see, what your application accesses, in combination with single-stepping through your code. You have the Qt source code for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is as if the os is making a copy of the config files and datbase files and keep updating them instead of the actual file.

That might indeed be the case. Windows Vista and above introduced the concept of the *Windows Virtual Store* to prevent applications from writing to possibly harmful locations. For an explaination see e.g. http://portableapps.com/node/35519

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I think I should move config files and DB files to another location during the first startup I guess. Is there any other general way to do so. Problem is during re-installation. Old files in virtual store are still considered.

Comment: If your program has a proper installation, you should store settings in a subfolder of `%APPDATA%`, as is the recommendation for installed programs. Uninstallation can then leave or delete that data as you wish.